# Openshift Java MySQL Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, mysql, openshift

I am working on Openshift, on a Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) with MySQL 5.5 and phpMyAdmin 4.0. I am trying to connect to the database, but everytime this `MySQLNonTransientConnectionException` jumps.

Originally, the exception was `Communication link failure`, but I added the autoReconnect thing to the URL (I read that it was a workaround to this problem), but it hasn't worked.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2385)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2306)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at bd.BdConnection.initConnection(BdConnection.java:35)
        at bd.BdConnectionTest.testConnection(BdConnectionTest.java:11)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:357)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2324)
        ... 40 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:307)
        ... 42 more
    pocketprod
    127.6.41.2
    3306
    admin2k9WkTx
    xcfcqjs9ZJQn
    Error al conectar con la base de datos
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 10 times. Giving up.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2385)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2306)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at bd.BdConnection.initConnection(BdConnection.java:35)
        at bd.BdConnection.getConnection(BdConnection.java:54)
        at bd.BdConnectionTest.testConnection(BdConnectionTest.java:12)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.executeMethodBody(TestMethodRunner.java:99)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runUnprotected(TestMethodRunner.java:81)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.runMethod(TestMethodRunner.java:75)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethodRunner.run(TestMethodRunner.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.invokeTestMethod(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassMethodsRunner.run(TestClassMethodsRunner.java:35)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner$1.runUnprotected(TestClassRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.BeforeAndAfterRunner.runProtected(BeforeAndAfterRunner.java:34)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner.run(TestClassRunner.java:52)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor3.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:357)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2479)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2324)
        ... 41 more
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:307)
        ... 43 more
```

Also, here is the code for the connection (I have used this same code, except for the autoreconnect part, in other project some months ago and it worked).

```
private Connection conexion = null;

public static boolean initConnection() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // Variables de entorno para crear la url de acceso
        String name = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME");
        System.out.println(name);
        String host = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST");
        System.out.println(host);
        String port = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT");
        System.out.println(port);

        // url de acceso a la bd
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + name + 
                "?autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10";

        // usuario y password de la bd
        String user = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME");
        System.out.println(user);
        String password = System.getenv("OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD");
        System.out.println(password);

        // crear la conexion con la bd
        conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

        return true;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Excepcion SQL 
        System.err.println("Error al conectar con la base de datos");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Excepcion del driver
        System.err.println("Driver de MySQL no encontrado");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have looked my `my.conf` file, and I cannot change the binding address, which is not set to 0.0.0.0 nor 127.0.0.1.

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT**: I cannot download the `my.conf` file from the server so I can say:

```
Configurable values:
lower_case_table_names
default-storage-engine
max_connections
ft_min_word_len
ft_max_word_len

Other things, but I cannot touch them:
skip-name-resolve
bind-address=127.6.41.2
```

Sorry if it's not entirely accurate, I cannot copy the file. I have seen in other answers the bind-address thing, but since I cannot change it...

Comment: can you add the my.conf to the question?

Comment: Ssh to openshift box and check values of env var that you are using. Try to use in initConnection() method hard coded connection string for the beginning.

Comment: I have hardcoded values but still not working. I did port forwarding too, trying to connect directly from my computer, but no luck in that case too.

Comment: Can you try sshing to your application and running the "mysql" command and see if it connects?

Comment: It connects. Anyway, I have decided to use SQLite because I don't think this is gonna be fixed any time soon (I think it is some configuration problem on the Openshift side, not something I can fix).